# How to set Home-Icon margins when using setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-homebutton

I have a problem with native actionbar (not ABS). In normal state icon has 26 px margins on both side.

[image]

But when I call [setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled%28boolean%29) it decreases this margins and in result it looks much narrower.

[image]

Do you have any idea how to maintain this margins when [setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled%28boolean%29) is called? (**prefferably** without workarounds and custom views)

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the **margin of the home-icon** like that: (just call the below code inside your Activity's `onCreate(...)` method)

```
ImageView ivIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.home);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams lpIcon = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) ivIcon.getLayoutParams();

lpIcon.topMargin = lpIcon.bottomMargin = yourmargin;
lpIcon.leftMargin = lpIcon.rightMargin = yourmargin;
ivIcon.setLayoutParams(lpIcon);
```

> Its kind of a **hack** but I used it to get rid of the margin completely by setting it to 0.